# Ubuntu versions and libraries

Tags: 14.04, libraries, versions

I tried searching for it and I might have used wrong keywords. Where can I find the libraries versions (or highest possible versions) that come with each Ubuntu version (or are available as deb packages)?

For example Ubuntu 14.04 has Opencv 2.4.x while newer versions come with Opencv 3.

Comment: AFAIK You have to install opencv in ubuntu and no Ubuntu comes with built-in Opencv libraries. It depends to you that what version of opencv must be installed in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always search on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/opencv)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, The most straightforward method of checking a version of a library in Ubuntu is using the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep <package name>
```

For example:

```
dpkg -l | grep php5-cli
```

returns:

```
ii  php5-cli          5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14      amd64        command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
```

Comment: I am not interested about the currently installed library but about the highest version of that library available for an Ubuntu version. For example Opencv 3 is not available as deb package for ubuntu 14.04. Where is this kind of information available?

Comment: The latest available is the same that is installed if you update your system.

Comment: This question is not related to Ubuntu. Have you checked http://opencv.org/ website?

Comment: It is actually...

Answer (score 0):

The list of precompiled packages/libraries and their versions available for some Ubuntu version (eg. 14.04) are available on this page:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/devel/